# URL error 404 Django page not found error x.html

Tags: python, html, django-views, django-templates

I haven't managed to find why it is giving the error?
A lot of answers received where copy-paste to gain exp in StackOverflow

So the situation is that my URL from my navbar.html return error 404 couldn't find x.html

here is the code for each py file :

views.py :

```
from django.shortcuts import render, redirect
from django.core.mail import send_mail, BadHeaderError
from django.http import HttpResponse, HttpResponseRedirect
from django.conf import settings
from .forms import ContactForm

# Create your views here.

def home_page(request):
    return render(request, 'index.html')

def education(request):
    return render(request, 'Education.html')

def experience(request):
    return render(request, 'Experience.html')

def portfolio(request):
    return render(request, 'Portfolio.html')
```

setting.py :

```
STATIC_URL = '/static/'
STATIC_ROOT = os.path.join(BASE_DIR, '../blog_level/static')
STATICFILES_DIRS= [
    os.path.join(BASE_DIR, 'static'),
]
```

navbar.html :

```
 <ul class="u-align-center u-nav u-popupmenu-items u-unstyled u-nav-2"><li class="u-nav-item"><a class="u-button-style u-nav-link" href="{% url 'homepage' %}" style="padding: 10px 0px; text-shadow: 0 0 8px rgba(128,128,128,1);">Home</a>
</li><li class="u-nav-item"><a class="u-button-style u-nav-link" href="{% url 'experience' %}" style="padding: 10px 0px; text-shadow: 0 0 8px rgba(128,128,128,1);">Experience</a>
</li><li class="u-nav-item"><a class="u-button-style u-nav-link" href="{% url 'education' %}" style="padding: 10px 0px; text-shadow: 0 0 8px rgba(128,128,128,1);">Study</a>
</li><li class="u-nav-item"><a class="u-button-style u-nav-link" href="{% url 'portfolio' %}" style="padding: 10px 0px; text-shadow: 0 0 8px rgba(128,128,128,1);">Portfolio</a>
</li><li class="u-nav-item"><a class="u-button-style u-nav-link" href="{% url 'homepage' %}#sec-1120" data-page-id="134427998" style="padding: 10px 0px; text-shadow: 0 0 8px rgba(128,128,128,1);">Contact</a>
</li></ul>
```

blog_level\urls.py :

```
from django.contrib import admin
from django.urls import path, re_path
from . import views

urlpatterns = [
    path('', views.home_page, name='homepage'),
    path('education/', views.education, name='education'),
    path('experience/', views.experience, name='experience'),
    path('portfolio/', views.portfolio, name='portfolio'),
]
```

fist_website_app_level.py :

```
"""first_website_app_level URL Configuration

The `urlpatterns` list routes URLs to views. For more information please see:
    https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/3.2/topics/http/urls/
Examples:
Function views
    1. Add an import:  from my_app import views
    2. Add a URL to urlpatterns:  path('', views.home, name='home')
Class-based views
    1. Add an import:  from other_app.views import Home
    2. Add a URL to urlpatterns:  path('', Home.as_view(), name='home')
Including another URLconf
    1. Import the include() function: from django.urls import include, path
    2. Add a URL to urlpatterns:  path('blog/', include('blog.urls'))
"""
from django.contrib import admin
from django.urls import path, include

urlpatterns = [
    path('', include('blog_level.urls')),


]
```

here below is the file structure of my project [image: file structure]

and please find the debug error :

[image: debugg error 404 page]

I still don't understand the error of the process why it won't link to the correct page, naturally based on the following expert at a simple project level.

https://github.com/CoreyMSchafer/code_snippets/blob/master/Django_Blog/03-Templates/django_project/blog/urls.py

Comment: You should visit `/experience/`, not `Experience.html`.

Answer (score 0):

Your url is wrong:
Instead of:

```
127.0.0.1:8000/Experience.html
```

use:

```
127.0.0.1:8000/experience
```

because you have 'experience' in your view: path('experience', ...)

Comment: What do you mean ?  when i click on experience it does load experience.html so where should i change the file issue ?

Comment: You should visit /experience/, not Experience.html. So remove '.html', in url, url have to look like is in your that is 'experience' in  path('experience').

Comment: what url.py i have two of them ??

Comment: I mean, you should visit: http://127.0.0.1:8000/experience and not http://127.0.0.1:8000/experience.html. don't add dot html (.html), because you have in your views: path('experience', ...) and not path('experience.html', ...)

Comment: I know that , it is what i am looking for but how do you do it then in code ?

Comment: there is no file issue! Django work like that: if you visit 127.0.0.1:8000/experience, django routing point to path ('experience /', views.experience, name = 'experience'), then call views.experience() which  return file: 'Experience.html'.

Comment: so what would be the change ?

Comment: Sorry ! I'd not look well your files architecture. Because something miss `blog_level/templates`: so **1)** You have to create another directory in your app templates named like your app so you will have: `blog_level/templates/blog_level/`. **2)** Move all your html in there: `blog_level/templates/blog_level/(all_html_file)`.

Comment: **3)** type this in your `project_first_web/project_first_website/settings.py` , to define the templates `path`: TEMPLATES = [
    {
        'BACKEND': 'django.template.backends.django.DjangoTemplates',
        'DIRS': [
            os.path.join(BASE_DIR, 'templates/')
            ],

Answer (score 0):

In `Django` `urls.py` is the file which has mapping between the `views` and `url`, so if you want to visit `Experience.html` page you have to have your `url` as `127.0.0.1:8000/experience` (nothing to change in the code, just update the URL you are using in your browser) because the `urls.py` has the mapping as `path('experience/', views.experience, name='experience'),`

[Here](https://www.tutorialspoint.com/django/django_url_mapping.htm) is a nice document on how url mapping works.

Comment: I have 2 url.py, one from the blog_level and one from the first_website_app_level, where should I change it?

Comment: You have nothing to change in your url.py, the url which you type in your browser should be changed to 127.0.0.1:8000/experience

Comment: what about my navbar.html